DBT Spark on EMR using AWS Glue Data Catalog
I have a classic infrastructure with AWS EMR with spark Jobs writing to hive tables located in S3 where the hive metastore is set to be AWS Glue DataCatalog.
Now I'm exploring lakehouse formats, such as delta lake and after being able to use it on EMR, I want to test installing dbt to run some transformations using my test delta tables. When configuring dbt-spark project it only has thrift option and no mention to glue data catalog.
Has anyone tried to use something similar?

I haven't been able to find a way to use EMR clusters specifically with DBT, however it is possible to use Glue and the Glue Data Catalog with the dbt-glue adapter from AWS to achieve what you are looking for. Here is an AWS blog post that describes the setup https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-and-manage-your-modern-data-stack-using-dbt-and-aws-glue-through-dbt-glue-the-new-trusted-dbt-adapter/
